# Javascript brackets error

Tags: javascript

Why do I get an error in this line? I cleaned up the code and let only the parts where it opens and closes.

Actually there is a parenthesis in more, but I can not figure out where.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("test", function(request, status) {

query.find().then(function(results) {

        for (var i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {

        }

    }).then(function() {

      Parse.Object.saveAll([array01, array02], {

        success: function(list) {

            if (status) {

            };

        }, error: function(model, error) {

            if (status) {

            };

        }); //THIS!!!!!!

    }, function(error) {

    });

})
});
```

Comment: Well, the `);` is just wrong there. You can't have that in the object literal. Don't you agree that `{ error: function() { }); }` looks kind of wrong?

Comment: sorry for spamming, SRSLY, you can't count braches?

Comment: `}); //THIS!!!!!!` to `} }); //THIS!!!!!!`

Comment: thanks but the problem then is the semicolon (in addition to the brackets)?

Comment: Something this convoluted suggests a misguided design. (perhaps not helped by the language) Poor indentation has obviously not helped you understand your own code - hopefully that's a good lesson for the future.

Comment: @FelixKling but OP has to close object literal right?

Comment: @MarioRossi: Both. You can't have semicolons inside an object literal either. The syntax is `{foo: bar, baz: xyz}` not `{foo: bar; baz: xyz;}`.

Comment: @vinayakj: It's closed in `}, function(error) {`.

Comment: then where is saveAll closing, the object literal of argument of  `saveAll` should close in `success callback` of `.then`

Comment: OP can you please try once changing `}); //THIS!!!!!!` to `} }); //THIS!!!!!!`

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling works and sorry guys for this stupid question. But the high temperatures get really bad jokes.

Comment: @FelixKling like the below answer by @bergi is what I was suggesting through that `} }); //THIS!!!!!!` If that makes sense what I was referring to

Comment: @vinayakj: I see. There could have been really multiple ways to fix the syntax, but of course only one makes sense given the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [reasonable indentation](http://jsbeautifier.org/), your script looks like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("test", function(request, status) {
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {}
    }).then(function() {
        Parse.Object.saveAll([array01, array02], {
            success: function(list) {
                if (status) {}
                ;
            },
            error: function(model, error) {
                if (status) {}
                ;
            }); //THIS!!!!!!
//           ^^
        }, function(error) {});
    })
});
```

which clearly shows the the `);` is too much there - in the middle of an object literal. The invocation of `Parse.Object.saveAll` ends only after that empty function callback. Alternatively, you might have wanted to do

```
Parse.Cloud.job("test", function(request, status) {
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < deals.length; i++) {}
    }).then(function() {
        return Parse.Object.saveAll([array01, array02], {
            success: function(list) {
                if (status) {}
            },
            error: function(model, error) {
                if (status) {}
            } // <-- close function body
        }); //THIS!!!!!!
    }, function(error) {
    });
    // <-- remove superfluous })
});
```

where `function(error) { }` is a callback to `then`, not to `saveAll`.